# Using an Eloquent relationship within an Eloquent accessor?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, accessor

I am writing a Laravel application that manages training courses.

Each course is represented by a Course model.

A course can have many dates - these are represented by a CourseDate model, with a hasMany relationship between the two:

Each course also has a single "date template", which is a CourseDate, but with an "is_template" boolean set.

I want to create an accessor on the Course model that retrieves its date template.

The (relevant) code for each model is:

```
class Course extends Model {
    public function getDateTemplateAttribute() {
        $dates = $this->dates;
        $filtered = $dates->where('is_template', true);
        $template = $filtered->first();
        return $template;
    }

    public function dates() {
        $result = $this->hasMany( CourseDate::class );
        return $result;
    }
}

class CourseDate extends Model {
    public function course() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Course::class );
    }
}
```

Then, in my controller, I have this:

```
// this block works absolutely perfectly
$course = Course::find(1);
$dates = $course->dates;
$working_date_template = $dates->where('is_template', true)->first();

// this one doesn't work at all and says "call to a member function first() on array"
$broken_date_template = $course->date_template;
```

Stepping through with xdebug in the broken code, the line `$dates = $this->dates` returns an empty array so everything else afterwards breaks.

Is this a limitation with the Laravel accessor/relationship system? Or am I just being dense and doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out just now.

I needed to use `$this->dates()` within the model itself as this returns the relationship and I can then filter it out accordingly using the `where()` method and other query builder methods.

This was, of course, mentioned in the Laravel documentation - I just didn't spot it.